Getting Error "e is not a function" When Exporting Data from angular-slickgrid
I'm using the excel export module of angular-slickgrid to export my list data but im keep getting error "e is not a function" in the console. i have attached the console logs and snippet of the issue. What can i do to resolve this issue?
case:

I'm using angular-slickgrid version 7.7.0.
This issue occurs only when the application is in production mode and size of the records are large.



